# How to get only id from many to many relationship SQLAlchemy

Tags: javascript, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        likedComments = db.relationship('Comment', secondary=user_likedComment, backref='likedby')

class Comment(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

user_likedComment = db.Table('user_likedComment', 
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('comment_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('comment.id'))
)
```

When I create this many-to-many relationship, accessing comment.likedby gives me a list of [<User "id">, ...]. This is a problem because when I try to compare a member of this list to a user.id it does not ever find it because it compares "<User "id">" to a single integer(user.id). How can I only get the id and not the class name or <> from the list. It's hard for me because I am accessing this list in html and can only iterate it through Jinja, and cannot use python. In html with Jinja:

```
    {% for cmt in forum.comments %}
    create comment
        {% for userId in cmt.likedby %}
            {% if user.id == userId %}
    check if user is in likedby list (never works because it compares integer "id" to "<User "id">")
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Normally, I would've sliced or index but cannot use that because it is in html, so i cannot use python. The list also cannot be used in javascript because it is from python.

Comment: Maybe `for u in cmt.likedby` followed by `if user.id == u.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmt.likedby` is a list of objects of type `User`.
So when you iterate through this list you should get `id` attribute of these objects:

```
    {% for cmt in forum.comments %}
    create comment
        {% for user_who_liked in cmt.likedby %}
            {% if user.id == user_who_liked.id %}
                Something...
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I will try this, initally I thought it wouldn't work because of the line db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')), Which i thought implied that it was stored as the user id and not object. Thanks

Comment: I tried this it work, Thanks